# XSLT For-Each Start a div that opens and closes around every 4th element

Tags: html, xslt, umbraco

So I have a template that displays staff profiles. Like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</div>
```

In my XSLT For-each loop I need a way to wrap that "div class=row" around every group of 4 list items. I can test for the count to see which element I am on, but the issue is wrapping groups of 4 in XSLT since you can't use modulus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> the issue is wrapping groups of 4 in XSLT since you can't use modulus.

Au contraire. :) What you want is the [`mod operator`](http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/operator_mod.html). Additionally, the `<xsl:for-each>` element is quite often not the most reusable approach; instead, consider a solution that makes use of more malleable templates.

**When this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vNumOfElems" select="4"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="li[position() mod $vNumOfElems = 1]"/>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="li">
    <div class="row">
      <xsl:copy-of
        select=".|following-sibling::li[not(position() &gt; $vNumOfElems - 1)]"/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is applied against the proposed source XML:**

```
<ul>
  <li/>
  <li/>
  <li/>
  <li/>
  <li/>
  <li/>
  <li/>
  <li/>
</ul>
```

**...the wanted result (though it might not pass the sniff-test of valid HTML) is produced:**

```
<ul>
  <div class="row">
    <li />
    <li />
    <li />
    <li />
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <li />
    <li />
    <li />
    <li />
  </div>
</ul>
```

Note the use of a variable -- `$vNumOfElems` -- to hold onto the number of elements that should be contained within a group. This provides convenience. **Down the road, should you need, say, 3 `<li>` elements per `<div>`, simply making that change:**

```
<xsl:variable name="vNumOfElems" select="3" />
```

**...again provides the correct result:**

```
<ul>
  <div class="row">
    <li />
    <li />
    <li />
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <li />
    <li />
    <li />
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <li />
    <li />
  </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow fantastic answer! I really appreciate the explanation and time you took to teach me something!! That works great!